# How do I remove a data restriction?

Tags: mobile-data

A couple of months ago I set my phone to have a data limit so that it would stop at 1GB. I have a plan that I share with 2 other people so I thought 1GB would keep my usage down. After a couple of weeks it just started turning my data off, even if I was just using Wifi. I disabled the data limit because it was super annoying.

Now, I get notifications that tell me that I have a data restriction (not limit) set. I don't know how to turn it off and it is super annoying. It says:

```
Data Restriction Enabled
touch notification to remove restriction
```

How do I turn this off?

---

Device: Motorola Droid Razr M
Android Version: 4.1.2 (JellyBean)

Comment: What about "touch notification to remove restriction?"

Comment: If I touch the notification the restriction temporarily goes away

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

Setting > Data usage > (Data usage Action bar menu) > uncheck 'Restrict background data'

hoped it helps.